# View.setLayoutParams() has no effect even after layout completed

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm working on an Android TV app and need to make a progress bar to indicate how much content has been played already. I feel like what I've written should be working, but it isn't.

I've got a `LinearLayout` with `android:orientation="horizontal"` and `android:weightSum=100` as a container for the progress bar, and the actual progress bar is a `FrameLayout` inside the container, with `android:layout_width="0dp"` and `android:layout_weight="0"` to make sure the progress bar isn't drawn if there isn't any progress.

In the activity code I'm attempting to change the weight of the progress bar like this:

```
ViewGroup.LayoutParams lp = progressView.getLayoutParams();
LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(lp.width, lp.height, progress);
progressView.setLayoutParams(params);
```

(`progressView`, naturally, is the progress bar object I'm trying to manipulate, and `progress` is the intended new weight)

I was initially running this code in the activity's `onCreate()` method, until I remembered you can't do anything about a view's dimensions until it has been laid out properly. Since then I've tried running this in `onResume()` with `postDelayed` like this:

```
@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    progressView.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            setProgress();
        }
    }, 1000);
}
```

and with a `ViewTreeObserver` like this during `onCreate()`:

```
progressView.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
    @Override
    public void onGlobalLayout() {
        if (!progressBarRefreshed) {
            setProgress();
        }
    }
});
```

and I've even tried running the code as an onClick event attached to a button in the same activity (in both cases `setProgress()` is the function that performs the weight change using the code posted above). I've verified (with log messages I removed from the code to make it more readable) that the initial width is 0, height is -1 (`match_parent`) and weight is 0, and that the new `LayoutParams` object has width 0, height -1 and weight equal to whatever I set it to. But after the `setLayoutParams()` call the view still has weight 0 and there is no change on the screen either. What blatantly trivial thing am I missing here?

Comment: are you aware of `ProgressBar` view?

Comment: @pskink I wasn't. I'll take a look at that and maybe stop trying to reinvent the wheel, thanks!

Comment: yes `reinventing the wheel` is always bad...

Answer (score 0):

Try calling `progressView.requestLayout()` after setting the layout params.